# Could all "auxiliary" be used at the beginning of the sentence

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, phrase-usage, usage

Could all "auxiliary" be used at the beginning of the sentence.

I often see the following sentence:
(You) Don't......=Don't
So like this kind of sentence, I will often use.

but I saw the following post in a forum:

> #### Cant put anything in user folder?
>
> Haven't had a windows box in a while. Just got a new HP with 8.1.
> If I remember right I could put files anywhere in my user folder. Now, with 8.1, I cant unless it's a sub folder?
> Can use Documents, Video etc...just not in the top folder. Is this a change?
> Thanks.

The first line is the title of the forum thread.

It uses a lot of "auxiliary" at the beginning of the sentences.
I sometimes want to use this same usage, but I have rarely seen this usage in English articles.

Is it a correct usage? Is it common?

Sometimes I feel using "subject" is verbose, I would like to use directly the following sentence. Is it OK?

1. Cant put anything...
2. Haven't had a windows box...
3. Can use Documents...
4. Should...
5. Shouldn't...
6. Will...
7. Won't...
   ...etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ellipses and how to decide which part I can omit as an ellipsis](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20894/ellipses-and-how-to-decide-which-part-i-can-omit-as-an-ellipsis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auxiliaries in this example are at the beginning of these sentences because the subject pronouns that would usually go before them have been omitted.

> (I) Haven't had a windows box in a while.

If you're asking whether it's correct to omit subject pronouns, no, it usually isn't. It can sometimes be done if the context of the statement allows the listener to infer what the subject is, but this very rarely used, and when it is used, it is only used infrequently and informally.

Generally, if you omit pronouns, people will have a hard time understanding what you're trying to say. It's best to include them, as pronouns really aren't optional.

Also, the correct contraction of "will not" is "won't".